# UIScrollView delegate not getting fire?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have subclassed UIScrollView and setting it's super class as delegate as shown in below snippet, even i have set contentSize:, delegate methods are not getting called.

```
popView = [[PopView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, y, 250, 40)];
popView.answerDelegate = self;
popView.delegate = self;
popView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(750, 40);
popView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self addSubview:popView];
```

One more thing, 'PopView' is subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: Are you getting any warning at popView.answerDelegate = self; ?

Comment: have you connect delegate from XIB for ScrollView?

Comment: no.. everything is fine.

Comment: I don't have any outlet or connections in xib

Comment: @Ash Where have you made call to your delegate method ?

Comment: I am loading 'PopView' for some action. In that method I am added above code.

Comment: Are you holding the `popView` in a property since you implemented the delegate methods there?

Comment: yes.. property is strong.

Comment: If it did get fire, this could potentially be a problem, as flames can be damaging to devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are subclassing UIScrollView then setting its delegate to self will not do anything. a scrollview cannot be its own delegate since it doesnt implement its delegate methods itself. the view that contains the scrollview needs to be the delegate for it and must implement its delegate functions for it to work properly.

also `self` != super class. `super` == super class

Comment: sorry, not your popview, but whatever `self` is ill change my answer

Comment: thanks:) I changed my subclass from UIScrollView to UIView.. now the delegate is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to adding your Scrollview using Xib then check are set delegate to file owner.and Adding .h file  Like this

```
@interface View : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

if not work yet then trying to clean your build. and then try...